# In IE11 Symbol.Iterator is giving error when i am using for each on array of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to loop an array of buttons and creating react component button at runtime, the error is reproducible only in IE 11 , I'm getting error in Symbol. Iterator which means that the array i am passing is non valid and internal iterator cannot be returned, but this works fine with any other browser, Is it a problem with IE or i am using jQuery selector to get the array of buttons.

```
export default function(buttons){

   for(let button of buttons){
       //Code for creating button as react component button.
   }
}

//call to replaceButtons


var btns = $('.continue-buttons');
replaceButtons(btns);
```

Getting error with 
[SYMBOL.ITERATOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator)

I know this is not optimized way to write react code but requirement and design is quite a challenge.

Comment: to test if it's the jQuery object that is causing the issue, make a proper array from the result ... `var btns = [].slice.call($('.continue-buttons'));`

Comment: You're missing a `var`/`let`/`const` declaration for `button`.

Comment: Sorry , i was sharing sample code, missed it out.

Comment: I changed to querySelectorAll and it's working fine, but why it is working for other browsers and not for IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery does not return an array, it returns a jQuery collection. <s>Which isn't iterable indeed.</s> [It actually is](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/08/jquery-2-2-and-1-12-released/) since v1.12/v2.2.

However, [Internet Explorer 11 just doesn't support iterators or `for of` loops](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) at all.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but i have a doubt that how come chrome, mozilla and edge is able to return the default iterator rather than the IE11?

Comment: There is no "default iterator". I doubt/don't understand how it worked in the other browsers. What *exactly* is the error message you get in IE? Also, what jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Jquery version 3.1.1 and The Symbol.iterator specifies the default iterator for an object from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator)

Comment: There is no "default iterator for an object", but yes jQuery is using `Array.prototype.values` (`[][Symbol.iterator]`)

Comment: Its IE11 which does not recognizing JQuery collection for Iterators, Thanks.